# Read from file to arraylist of object, why I get IOException?

Tags: java, arraylist, file-read

I write a method which saves my arraylist of clients to file. After that, at the beginning of my program I wanna read from file and get all clients to the arraylist. My problem is that program throws IOException and also these notes:

```
Note: test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

My code:

```
    ArrayList<Client>accountList=new ArrayList<Client>();
    File fileRead=new File("file.txt");

    try{
        FileInputStream arrayAccountsList=new FileInputStream(fileRead);
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(arrayAccountsList);
        accountList=(ArrayList<Client>)ois.readObject();
        arrayAccountsList.close();

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
    }
    catch(IOException d){
        System.out.println("IOEXCEPTION");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException f){
        System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");
    }
```

Can you tell me what I did wrong here? Much thanks.

EDIT:

stacktrace output:

```
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2624)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3099)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:853)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
at Bank.main(Bank.java:23)
```

23 line is:

```
ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(arrayAccountsList);
```

Comment: Use `IOException#printStackTrace` to find the cause and post it here.

Comment: after `catch(IOException d){` add `d.printStackTrace();` statement and edit the question and paste the output

Comment: I edited it, any ideas?

Comment: I didn't get any errors when running your code. The stacktrace you posted doesn't have the actual exception, there should be more.